# Prove or disprove : Every factor ring of an integral domain is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to know

> Every factor ring of an integral domain is an integral domain

is true or not.

Is there any relevant theorem or cor, to prove or disprove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is every factor ring of the integral domain $\Bbb Z$
(after all the quintessential integral domain) an integral domain?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

What's the definition of a prime ideal?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/828805)

Comment: I didn't intend to provide a solution, only a hint. Anyone who can answer this question can answer the O.P.'s question.

Comment: @Bernard, i notice your intention. you mean $I$ is prime ideal iff $R/I$ is integral domain.

Comment: Yes. So if the assertion were true, all ideals would be prime…